# Struggle when reading files C++

Tags: c++

I hope u can help me. I've got a problem in my code. I am a beginner in C++ and I tried to create a binary file and to put 3 integers in it. After that I tried to read from that file but i dont get the right output. Here's my code:

```
int main() {
 ofstream izlazni_tok("BROJEVI.DAT", ios::binary);
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 int broj;
 cin >> broj;
 izlazni_tok.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&broj), sizeof broj);
 }
 ifstream ulazni_tok("BROJEVI.DAT", ios::binary);
 int broj;
 while(ulazni_tok.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&broj), sizeof broj))
 cout << broj << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: It is normal it is a struggle :)

Comment: Another suggestion on how to get better help (both from others and yourself) - format your code nicely.  With nicely indented code problems can sometimes become obvious where once they were hidden.

Comment: You should close a file before opening it again; or open the file as read and write (use `std::fstream`).

Comment: -- "Hey John, for our new project, what rules would you enforce regarding coding style?" --"I don't know Jon, what do you think about a one space indent, but only for function definitions, and a zero-width separator for all other scopes?" -- "Sound good John."

Comment: @YSC So who's to blame - Jon for suggesting it, John for agreeing with it, or Johnathan for not ignoring it and changing the coding style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the output stream to make sure that your writes are flushed:

```
  izlazni_tok.close();
```

before you attempt to read the file. Or alternatively:

```
  izlazni_tok.flush();
```

And a word of advice, always program in English. It makes it a lot easier for you to get help.

Comment: Alternatively adding a scope around the first part would probably do that for you. (Right now the ofstream is still in scope when you create the ifstream)

Comment: +1 for the word of advice. It is also good to note that only few languages can be written with ASCII without making language-purists furious.